# Populate view list box from text file with WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to generate a view like this:[image]

Right now my view model FileViewModel has RelayCommand for executing openfiledialog, and a property for file path. I am sending a file path to model called FileModel from FileViewModel.

```
var fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog {};
fileDialog.DefaultExt = ".txt";
fileDialog.ShowDialog();
path = fileDialog.FileName;
_fileModel = new FileModel(path);
```

FileModel has functions to read values (Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4) from selected file. 
I want to display these values in my view. I am not sure how to add that functionality to FileViewModel.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What is the view for each box? (`ListView`, `Treeview`, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an event in `FileModel` as `RaiseValuesChanged`. This will be raised after you have the Values you need from the `OpenFileDialog` in the `FileModel`. Pass the values thus read from the file as `EventArgs`
2. Add a Property which would hold the values from the Model, perhaps an `ObservableCollection<YOURVALUEsTYPE>()` or something.
3. Subscribe the model's `RaiseValuesChanged` in the FileViewModel, and in the handler, update the `ObservableCollection<YOURVALUEsTYPE>`
4. And you will need to bind this collection to your View of course..